# facebook extending the access token

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-access-token, extending

Hi I've seen the answer here 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation
and gave it a go but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I have an expired token - but obviosuly just need a way to auto update it.
is this possible can someone slip me some code

At present I'm trying this

```
try {
$result = $facebook->api(
                '/me/permissions/',
                'get',
                array('access_token' => $token)
        );
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

    echo "token invalid";
    $facebook->setAccessToken($token);
    echo $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();
}
```

But I still get

```
token invalid{"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1338858000. The current unix time is 1338985046.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":463}}
```

Any help. Thanks
Richard

---

Hi thanks for your help I've got the extended stuff to work and I'm understanding a little more
- I have a followup question say my token becomes invalid - what to do then?
I'm still logged into facebook and I've given permission to my app so it's all there I just need a new key.

I've tried this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => FACEBOOKAPPID,
                'secret' => FACEBOOKSECRET,
                'cookie' => true,
            ));

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=>1,'fbconnent'=>1,'scope'=>'offline_access,publish_stream,email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_website'));
file_get_contents($url);
$fb_session = $facebook->getUser();
echo $fb_session.'<br />';

$token = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();           
echo $token.'<br />';
```

As it seems that you need to 'login' to facebook to get the details again but it seems that you can't use file_get_contents as facebook requires the cookie that is on your machine. I'm trying to do this on the fly so not to bother the user with any popups and also they have already given the app permission.

Any ideas?
Richard

Oh and just doing this doesn't seem to work either.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->fbApiKey,
    'secret' => $this->fbSecretKey,
    'cookie' => true,
));
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: You can not extend a invalid token, only valid tokens are extendable

Comment: Interesting so how do you extend a valid one? and indeed how do they become invalid

Comment: Short-lived access token are valid for one to two hours, after that they expire and you’ll have to get a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $this->fbApiKey,
    'secret' => $this->fbSecretKey,
    'cookie' => true,
));
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Cheers - is that basically using the cookie that I have set with facebook to get a new access token. So if i don't have that cookie then it won't get a new token?

Comment: if you set cookie false then you can also able to get new token.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Removal of offline_access permission](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/):

> **Scenario 4: Client-side OAuth and Extending Access_Token Expiration Time through New Endpoint**
>
> Using the new endpoint below, you will be able to extend the
>   expiration time of an **existing, non-expired, short-lived user
>   access_token**. Please note, the endpoint can only be used to extend the
>   short-lived user access_tokens. If you pass an access_token that had a
>   long-lived expiration time, the endpoint will simply pass that same
>   access_token back to you without altering or extending the expiration
>   time

Once the long lived access token expires you'll need to get a new short lived token and then extend it.
As for "how to extend it", it's on the same post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```